# Error while deploying Azure webjob with 20 Minute interval

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

When I am deploying the Windows Azure webjob with recurring schedule of 20 Minute interval, I get an error.

My webjob publish settings are -

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
  "webJobName": "JobShiftManager",
  "startTime": "2016-09-20T00:00:00+05:30",
  "endTime": "2099-09-20T00:00:00+05:30",
  "jobRecurrenceFrequency": "Minute",
  "interval": 20,
  "runMode": "Scheduled"
}
```

But, when I change the schedule to 1 hour interval, I am able to deploy it successfully. My Azure instance size is B1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that you're using the Free Azure Scheduler, which doesn't support more than hourly runs.

Two options:

1. Upgrade to the paid Azure scheduler
2. Don't use Azure Scheduler at all, and instead rely on the WebJobs CRON support (see [docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateScheduledCRON)) for details. The requires a Basic or higher site with Always On enabled.